# unable to find error showing place in vue js

Tags: laravel, vue.js

working with vue js and Laravel project. when I upload an Image to the system my browser console got following error `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) HKGrotesk-Medium.woff2:1` and when I open that link it shows following url `http://localhost:8000/static/fonts/hk-grotesk/HKGrotesk-Medium.woff2` I unable to find out where is place in my project those files are. do you have an idea?

Comment: Hard without the actual project. Don't you load some fonts in your CSS or from a CDN?

Comment: I have some fonts in my public/fonts folder and those are working properly. but I don't know from where propagate above font